# Issue When Uploading to Meta Resumable Upload API

Tags: node.js, express, multipartform-data, multer, whatsapp

I am trying to use Meta's Resumable Upload API from my express.js server following Meta's [Resumable Upload API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/upload/).

**Expected:**
The file will get uploaded to Meta and I will get the uploaded file's file handle and then use it when submitting a new message template to meta cloud API.

**Reality:**
The session is being created, then the file gets uploaded - meta return status 200 with file handle **but** when sending the message template with this file as a component, the message template is being created successfully but the image is not being displayed and showing this error:

```
"The image “https://scontent.whatsapp.net/v/t61.29466-34/328144331_769747961297373_869675688279262698_n.png?ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=57045b&_nc_ohc=X5Z1yhl9zjcAX_liGN_&_nc_ht=scontent.whatsapp.net&oh=01_AdQ1uedUvMZ3tpCD2ziI76WlBaOW96PAD1BVh3Akj5LovQ&oe=64BE3307” cannot be displayed because it contains errors."
```

Also when checking the upload status of the upload session it shows the results below:

**Request:**

GET https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/upload:MTphdHRhY2htZW50OmQ2Y....

**Response:**

```
{"id":"MTphdHRhY2htZW50OmQ2Y....","file_offset":0}
```

**My Code:**
I use Multer memoryStorage as follows:

```
import multer from 'multer'

const storage = multer.memoryStorage()
const upload = multer({ storage })

const router = express.Router()

router.post(
  Routes.UPLOAD_FILE_TO_META,
  upload.single('file'),
  uploadFileToMeta
)

export default router
```

Function to create Resumable Upload Session

```
const createResumableUploadSession = async (fileLength: number, fileType: string): Promise<{ id: string }> => {
    try {
      const result = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: `https://graph.facebook.com/${process.env.META_API_VERSION}/${process.env.META_APP_ID}/uploads`,
        params: { file_length: fileLength, file_type: fileType },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.META_ACCESS_TOKEN}` }
      })
      return result.data
    } catch (err: unknown) {
      throw Error(`Meta API Create Resumable Upload Session request failed. error: ${err}`)
    }
  }
```

Function to initiate resumable upload session

```
const initiateResumableUploadSession = async (uploadSessionId: string, file: Express.Multer.File ): Promise<{ h: string }> => {
    try {
      const formData = new FormData()

      formData.append('file', file.buffer, {
        filename: file.originalname,
        contentType: file.mimetype
      })

      const result = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: `https://graph.facebook.com/${process.env.META_API_VERSION}/${uploadSessionId}`,
        data: formData,
        headers: {
          Authorization: `OAuth ${process.env.META_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
          'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData.getBoundary()}`
        }
      })
      return result.data
    } catch (err: unknown) {
      throw Error(`Meta API Initiate Resumable Upload Session request failed. error: ${err}`)
    }
  }
```

**Note:**
when repeating the same two requests directly to Meta in Postman it **does work!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information provided and the code snippets, it seems like there might be an issue with the way you're handling the file data during the upload. The error message you mentioned (`"The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors"`) suggests that there might be an issue with the uploaded file's content or format.

Try this modified code for the `initiateResumableUploadSession` function:

```
const initiateResumableUploadSession = async (uploadSessionId: string,file: Express.Multer.File): Promise<{ h: string }> => {
try {
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('file', file.buffer, {
  filename: file.originalname,
  contentType: file.mimetype
});

const result = await axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: `https://graph.facebook.com/${process.env.META_API_VERSION}/${uploadSessionId}`,
  data: formData,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.META_ACCESS_TOKEN}`, // Use 'Bearer' instead of 'OAuth'
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' // Use 'multipart/form-data'
  }
});

return result.data;

} catch (err: unknown) {

  throw Error(`Meta API Initiate Resumable Upload Session request failed.error: ${err}`);

 }
 };
```

Additionally, ensure that you have correctly configured your `Express.js` server to handle `CORS`, as issues related to `CORS` can also result in errors when working with APIs.

After making these changes, try uploading the file again and check if the issue persists.

Comment: Thanks!, `initiateResumableUploadSession` function works now as its uploading the file, **but** the file is still seems to be corrupted - "The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors", you ,mentioned CORS, what do you think might fix the issue, i use basic cors from [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) library?

Answer (score 0):

I have done it, but using other npms and I am using the JS version of the express,

Might be the issues are in your request for resumable upload API, you will get an idea from this code, and might be helpful for you,

> As I can see you are using TS syntax, Try to convert the basic things to TS from below JS code!

Your imports and constants are good, just add one more import,

```
import got from 'got';
```

The helper function to send the create session request,

```
/**
 * RESUMABLE UPLOAD - CREATE SESSION
 * https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/upload#step-1--create-a-session
 * https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/whats-app-business-account/message_templates/
 */
// RESUMABLE UPLOAD - CREATE SESSION
function createResumableUploadSession(body) {
    try {
        return got.post(["https://graph.facebook.com", process.env.META_API_VERSION, process.env.META_APP_ID, "uploads"].join("/"), { 
            headers: { 
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + process.env.META_ACCESS_TOKEN,
                'Accept': '*/*'
            },
            json: body,
            responseType: 'json',
            throwHttpErrors: false
        });
    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    }
}
```

The helper function to send the upload media request,

```
/**
 * RESUMABLE UPLOAD - INITIATE UPLOAD
 * https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/upload#step-2--initiate-upload
 * https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/whats-app-business-account/message_templates/
 */
// RESUMABLE UPLOAD - INITIATE UPLOAD
function initiateResumableUploadSession(uploadSessionId, body) {
    try {
        return got.post(["https://graph.facebook.com", process.env.META_API_VERSION, uploadSessionId].join("/"), { 
            headers: { 
                'Authorization': 'OAuth ' + process.env.META_ACCESS_TOKEN,
                'Accept': '*/*',
                'file_offset': 0
            },
            body: body,
            responseType: 'json',
            throwHttpErrors: false
        });
    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    }
}
```

The main function,

```
async function uploadFileToMeta(req, res) {
    // UPLOAD
    upload.single('file')(req, res, async (error) => {
        // PROBABLY FILE SIZE ERROR
        if (error instanceof multer.MulterError) {
            // LOG ERROR, AND RESPONSE
            console.error(error);
            res.status(400).send({
                message: `Max file size ${fileSize} allowed!`
            });
        }
        // SOMETHING OTHER ERROR 
        else if (error) {
            // LOG ERROR, AND RESPONSE
            console.error(error);
            res.status(400).send({
                message: `Something went wrong please try again!`
            });
        }
        // FILE IS REQUIRED
        else if (!req.file) {
            // LOG ERROR, AND RESPONSE
            res.status(400).send({
                message: `File is required!`
            });
        }
        else {
            // CREATE SESSION
            let session = await createResumableUploadSession({
                file_length: req.file.size,
                file_name: req.file.originalname,
                file_type: req.file.mimetype
            });
            if (session.body.error) {
                // LOG ERROR, AND RESPONSE
                console.error(session.body.error);
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: session.body.error.error_user_title ? session.body.error.error_user_title + ` (${session.body.error.error_user_msg})` : session.body.error.message
                });
            }
            //INITIATE UPLOAD
            let iupload = await initiateResumableUploadSession(session.body.id, req.file.buffer);
            if (iupload.body.h) {
                // SUCCESS RESPONSE
                console.error(iupload.body);
                return res.status(200).send({
                    message: "Uploaded!",
                    body: iupload.body
                });
            }
            // ERROR
            else if (iupload.body.error) {
                // LOG ERROR, AND RESPONSE
                console.error(iupload.body.error);
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: iupload.body.error.error_user_title ? iupload.body.error.error_user_title + ` (${iupload.body.error.error_user_msg})` : iupload.body.error.message
                });
            }
            else {
                // LOG ERROR, AND RESPONSE
                console.error(iupload);
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: "Something went wrong please try again!"
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Your final router call,

```
router.post(Routes.UPLOAD_FILE_TO_META, uploadFileToMeta)
```

---

This exact example is implemented in [This Repo](https://github.com/turivishal/meta-resumable-upload-api), you can clone and play with it.

Comment: Thank you for your time! but the problem is on Meta's side. No matter how you send the file and from where it seems to be corrupted. but its not a big issue for templates. The template still getting accepted :D